# $.ajax succeeds with incorrect callback : reports failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following jquery.  When I set a breakpoint in the callback functions, it calls the error callback although the status field is 200.  I'm sure it's something stupid on my part, but I can't see it.  Thanks.

I modified the error function according to the jquery docs, and now I find the error identifies itself as a parse error (SyntaxError: Unexpected token <).  The response is html (it displays correctly), the error suggests that I need to modify data type information so this is accepted.  How?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../php/recordInteraction.php",
    type: 'GET',
    data : {
        'rId' : 'image'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        switch(response.status){
        case 'saved':
            alert(response.message); // do what you want
            break;
        case 200 :
                    $("#view1").html(arg.responseText);
            alert(response.message); // do what you want
            break;
        case 'empty':
            alert(response.message);
            break;
        default:
            alert("unknown response");
        }
    },
    error:function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){  // updated in edit.
        alert("failure" + textStatus);
        $("#view1").html(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: In `case 200` in the `success` function, you use `arg.responseText`, but `arg` isn't defined in that function...

Comment: Likely returning invalid json. Validate response at jsonlint.com

Comment: what is the alert message ?

Comment: The alert message is: failure + Object[object]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was specifying dataType:json.  Changing this to html fixed the problem.